# Elliptic Curve Blind Signature Implementation

Tags: elliptic-curves, blind-signature, blinding

I have seen this prior post: [Elliptic Curve based blind signature implementation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17635/elliptic-curve-based-blind-signature-implementation)

Currently I'm sizing up how difficult it would be to attain Elliptic Curve Blind signatures for an application I'm working on.

I did see this [posting from @DrLecter](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/16050/29315) which was very informative.

How difficult is it to implement an ECC Blind Signature Scheme? is there anything out there already to start with? What schemes are considered reputable and secure? I'm trying to determine if I need to start with a whitepaper, develop an algo and code.

An RSA scheme is probably not to useful for me due to signature sizes.

Comment: You first need to find a secure scheme. I've seen ECC blind signature papers describing schemes that are clearly not secure. The lucre paper is relatively well known, so it have seen some analysis.

Comment: hello, Lucre is not based in ECC. that's an implementation of Chaum's blind sig concept.

Comment: If you look at http://anoncvs.aldigital.co.uk/lucre/theory2.pdf , it's clearly *group* based crypto, not *RSA* based crypto. AFAIK the main point of lucre was avoiding Chaum's (now expired) patents on RSA based blind signatures.

Comment: Related: [A note on blind signature schemes - Matthew Green's blog](http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/p/note-on-blind-signature-schemes.html)

Comment: ok not sure what this has to do with my original question.

Comment: As a starting point, you can use the paper ["Blind Signature Schemes Based on
the Elliptic Curve Discrete Logarithm Problem"](https://sic.ici.ro/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/SIC_2010-4-Art7.pdf) and start developing from there.